# Androidで画面回転時のアニメーションをオフにしたい。

Tags: android, java

Android-javaの開発において、
画面回転時のアニメーションをオフにしたいです。
つまり、画面がくるっと回るのではなく、ただActivityなりFragmentが再起動されるだけでいいのですが、どうやってアニメーションをオフにすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APIレベル18以上であれば、
Activity内で以下の方法を使うことでアニメーションを無効にできます。

```java
Window window = getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = window.getAttributes();
attrs.rotationAnimation = WindowManager.LayoutParams.ROTATION_ANIMATION_JUMPCUT;
window.setAttributes(attrs);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。今手元に端末がなくてラフな質問で恐縮ですが、横向き固定（右横・左横をセンサーで切り替える状態）を入れてても動作しますでしょうか？縦横だったらわかるのですが、横横の場合に何か制限ってありましたっけ？

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957772/disable-default-animation-from-portrait-to-landscape

Comment: HTV32で試して見ましたがAndroid7.0で機能しませんでした。

Comment: '  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        
        Window window = getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = window.getAttributes();
        attrs.rotationAnimation = WindowManager.LayoutParams.ROTATION_ANIMATION_JUMPCUT;
        window.setAttributes(attrs);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }'これでいけました。ありがとう。

Comment: 質問が解決したのでしたら解決済みにしていただけるとうれしいです。

Comment: 解決済みにしました。ありがとうございました。